# Структура проекта Django

Tags: python, django

У меня есть небольшой проект(API) в котором есть модель User и модель Resume. Суть в  том, что пользователь может создать резюме. Резюме связан с пользователем по ForeignKey. Для работы с каждой из этих моделей будет создан ряд методов(такие как update, create, get и прочие). Вопрос заключается в следующем: Нужно ли создавать приложение для каждой из этих моделей, или все же все модели должны быть в одном приложении? Последний вариант напрягает меня тем, что это создаст нагромождение, поскольку все методы будут прописаны в одном файле views.py :/ 
Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Можно разделить vievs.py на несколько файлов, это не проблема

Comment: Приведите, если не трудно, небольшой пример, как именно это сделать правильно. Буду очень вам признателен

Comment: https://code-examples.net/ru/q/1d52eb

Answer (score 0):

Если следовать философии Django то лутче сделать два апликейшена для User и Resume. Как мне кажется в этом не должно быть проблемы и код будет чище.

Comment: Это как раз-таки создает проблему. Есть проблема при импорте моделей из одного приложения в другое